# Android Material Button Toggle Group - Check None Selected

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components, android-togglebutton

I am using `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` with single selection (only one button checked at a time). How to check if none of the buttons is checked?

```
        toggleGroup?.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.first_materialButton -> {
                    // do something when selected
                }

                R.id.second_materialButton -> {
                    // do something when selected
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution would be to get the `checkedButtonId` from the group on the else branch for `isChecked`, and if it the value is -1, then no button is selected.

```
toggleGroup?.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        when (checkedId) {
            R.id.first_materialButton -> {
                // do something when selected
            }

            R.id.second_materialButton -> {
                // do something when selected
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (group.checkedButtonId == View.NO_ID) {
           // do something when nothing selected
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need a listener check the [@Laura's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986879/2016562).

Otherwise you can use the **`getCheckedButtonIds()`** methods:

```
List<Integer> ids = materialButtonToggleGroup.getCheckedButtonIds();
if (ids.size() == 0){
  //Case unckecked
}
```

If you want to require a single selection you can use the `app:singleSelection="true"` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    ..>
```

This attribute requires a minimum of version `1.2.0-alpha03`.